# Unable to upgrade custom BNA in IBM Starter Plan

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have deployed my custom business network on (free) IBM Blockchain Starter Plan.

Reffered https://hackernoon.com/deploy-a-business-network-on-free-ibm-blockchain-starter-plan-93fafb3dd997

Now i want to redeploy my .bna after doing some changes.
I found this following commands for upgrade:

```
composer network install -a NETWORK-FILENAME.bna -c peeradmin@hlfv1
composer network upgrade -c peeradmin@hlfv1 -n NETWORK-NAME -V NETWORK-VERSION
```

But  this **peeradmin@hlfv1** card is not in the card list.

In my network adminCard has the role of **PeerAdmin** and **ChannelAdmin**

```
 composer card create -f adminCard.card -p connection-profile.json -u admin -c ./credentials/admin-pub.pem -k ./credentials/admin-priv.pem --role PeerAdmin --role ChannelAdmin
```

So i tried to install the new .bna using

```
composer network install -a NETWORK-FILENAME.bna -c adminCard.card
```

But this error is coming

```
Error: The business network is already installed on all the peers
```

Answer (score 1):

This error `Error: The business network is already installed on all the peers` usually means that you forgot to update the version number in the `package.json` file when you re-built the BNA file.

If you run `composer network ping` you should see the Business Network Version currently running, and if you run `composer archive list` it will list the version from the BNA (package.json).  If these 2 versions are the same then you need to update the package.json.  (If they are different it is possible that you have already installed the new version, but not started it so you can run the composer network start command.)

(The admin card you need to use is the one that you used when you first installed and started the network. You often see PeerAdmin@hlfv1 used in examples as it is the one used by the delelopment fabric tools - but it doesn't really apply for hosted Fabrics)

I think you should be able to see the versions currently installed and started by looking at the starter plan GUI.

If this doesn't help, you should raise a support ticket with IBM Cloud support.

Comment: I am able to install the network. i have changed the .bna name and its installed, but now the upgrade command is throwing error that could not find chaincode

Comment: If the .bna is installed successfully, then you should be able to use the `composer archive list` command to get the exact name and version of the network that you should use with the `composer network upgrade` command.